# Ways to play swf movies without using flash plugin

Tags: jquery, html, flash

Is there a possible way to play swf movies on your site without using the flash plugin? So i can prevent the pop up prompting users to download the latest version of flash?

I not sure if it's possible, but if there is anyway to pull that off, please share!

Thanks for any ones time.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is possible using HTML5 Video Tag

http://diveintohtml5.info/video.html

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

You have to offer as many video formats, as you can, because Different Browsers support different video formats.
You can do so, using source element.

There is also a better solution if you use Media Element.

http://mediaelementjs.com/

If you serve only some video formats, than MediaElement does a flash play fallback to play that video, which means another chance to play the video.

Comment: Thanks! For a swf video. What would the type be? type="video/swf"?